# svg disappears without rect border

Tags: css, svg

I have the following svg:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1 Tiny//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11-tiny.dtd">

<svg
    id="dude"
    version="1.1"
    baseProfile="basic"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
    viewBox="0 0 300 300"
    preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
    class="global"
>
    <style type="text/css"><![CDATA[
        .global {
            fill: grey;
        }
        .dude {
            fill: white;
        }
    ]]></style>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="300" height="300" stroke-width="0" />
    <g transform="translate(150,375)">
        <g class="dude" transform="scale(0.85)">
            <circle cx="0" cy="-300" r="90" />
            <circle cx="0" cy="-75" r="130" />
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

It works fine, but the `<rect>` is not needed. However when I remove it then the whole svg disappears. I thought maybe its because there is no width and height. But even if I add this via CSS, the svg disappears.

https://jsfiddle.net/L5v9tpsm/

How can I get the circles and background to show, without the `<rect>`?

Comment: You removed the colored background the rectangle provided, so now what’s left are a couple of _white_ elements, shown on a _white_ background … So go and specify a different `fill` color for `.dude` then.

Comment: cheers @CBroe, that's the answer. My incorrect assumption was that because I had assigned class="global" to the svg itself, this was what was getting the grey fill

Comment: The `<svg>` element itself doesn’t have anything that `fill` could work on, but you could set `background-color` instead.

Comment: @CBroe background-color would only work if the SVG was embedded in a HTML web page. That doesn't look to be the case here.

Comment: the weird thing is that i never set the rect to fill with grey. i set it for the svg itself, which then passed it on to the rect. background-color is a good solution for what i want tho. thanks.